# CSV Emitter for BIRT 4.2.2

Tags: eclipse, birt

I am currently using BIRT 4.2.2, to be exact it is 'ver. 4.2.2.v201210101433-8F8j7cFT0z0-TtIsTlT0z-a'.

I read on some online tutorial stating that there's a built-in CSV emitter for BIRT but I couldn't locate it with BIRT 4.2.2.  Is the built-in CSV emitter comes in at a later version of BIRT or CSV emitter is not bundled with BIRT and I have to download the CSV emitter myself?

I located a CSV emitter plugin on [here](https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/csv-emitter-birt-plugin/).  Is this where I should be getting the CSV emitter plugin for BIRT?

Comment: I think the out of the box excel emitter may actually be a CSV emitter.  Have you tried using it too meet your need?

Comment: Out of the box, the Excel emitter generates XLS spreadsheet in XML using the microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet XML schema.

Answer (score 1):

BIRT has a special EngineTask for extracting data from a report: IDataExtractionTask.

http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/deploy/reportEngineAPI.php#idataextractiontask

It is not an emitter, it is just a task - a class from the BIRT Engine API. You will have to program "a bit" yourself.

The CSV emitter you mentioned in the question is not bundled with BIRT.